# When to use , vs str()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def mymath(a, b):
    print("Add: " + str(a+b))
    print("Multiply: " + str(a*b))
    print("Divide: ", a/b)
    print("Subtract: ", a-b)

mymath(10, 15)
```

I was wondering if it makes a difference in using `+ str(var1 + var2)` vs `, var1, var2`?  If it does, when should I be using one or the other?

Comment: For one thing, the comma adds another space in between (notice the two spaces in the Subtract and Divide lines). You can fix that with `print("Subtract:", a-b)` or `print("Subtract: ", a-b, sep="")`

Comment: Oh okay, thank you.  So does it make a difference which one I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read the manual](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does and written to the stream, separated by `sep` and followed by `end`.

So if you pass a *single* argument to `print` (e.g., `"Multiply: " + str(a*b)`), `sep` is not inserted between them. (So no extra space character.)

All these lines are the same (the difference being how many times `str` is called behind-the-scenes and how many intermediate strings are constructed):

```
print("Multiply:", a*b)
print("Multiply: " + str(a*b))
print("Multiply: ", a*b, sep="")
```

Answer (score 3):

This use of `,` is specific to the `print` function. It automatically inserts a space. It is best to use for readability's sake when the space is desired, because it avoids the `str` call.

But, if you need a string (e.g. to put in a variable), you need to use `+str(...)`.

Comment: It doesn't avoid the `str` call, it just hides it.

Comment: @dom0: It avoids it from the readability point of view. That's all that matters when considering style.